# How to get old and new value of property of NSPropertyDescription

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData stack set up, able to retrieve the edit history for specific objects and so forth. I can even identify which property changed.
However I'm struggling with getting the old and new value of the property. See my code below. Is this even possible? If so, how?

```swift
func apply(_ changeItem: NSPersistentHistoryChange) {
    switch changeItem.changeType {
    case .update:
        guard let updatedProperties = changeItem.updatedProperties else { break }

        updatedProperties.forEach { (property) in
            // Get old and new value here
        }
    case .insert:
        // ...
    }
    // ...

}
```

Comment: Hey,
I want to do exactly the same - but don't know how. Have you solved that problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no :(

Comment: @FlorianLeitner found a solution / workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem I was facing:

- I couldn't identify the record to update in the destination store.

#### Workaround:

- Use an identifier field in the Entity
- That way you can query based on the identifier and update destination store with the new values
- identifier will not / should not change after insertion

Comment: Do you need just to update all changed object to new values?  Or make some operations in between (resolve some conflicts etc.)?

Comment: I wanted the old value to identify the record to update, now I use a separate identifier (unique key) and just use identifier to identify the record to update. Identifier for a record will not change in my code. It just turns out a design issue on my part, which I have managed to resolve using an identifier

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn’t your case but as I guess you have `NSPersistentHistoryChange` from `NSPersistentHistoryTransation`. In this case you can merge whole changes from that transaction all at once by merging it into context
Example:

```swift
 guard let userInfo = transaction.objectIDNotification().userInfo else { return }           
NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: userInfo, into: [context])
```

In your specific secnerio I didn't found how to find old value in `NSPersistentHistoryChange`. Maybe `userInfo` contains this information

Comment: Thanks, but userInfo doesn't contain old values, in my case I could handle it by having an identifier which IMHO is better approach.